# Can you drop and reacquire the Hanar Diplomat quest?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I, along with others, went and did something else while in the middle of the Hanar Diplomat mission, and so can't access any of the relevant terminals and thus save the hanar from whatever naughtiness is being planned.

Now, I hear that there is a Mass Effect 3 Gibbed save editor out now; is it worth downloading in order to uncheck the quest box (so to speak) and re-acquire the quest? Or are my hanar consigned to not knowing what their diplomat is doing before it is too late?

Comment: Anything that edits your save file is potentially dangerous if you also play multiplayer.

Comment: I found a page with codes for various quests, found the Hanar Diplomat one, and tried out deleting that code from the quest list in Gibbed (I did this on an older save file to avoid the whole multiplayer problem). It did not work as I would've hoped (Kasumi didn't come along again, and the hanar surveillance was greyed out on the Spectre panel), so I decided to just skip it and wait for the patch. Poot.

Comment: The problem is that Patch might not solve the problem on pre-existing saves, but prevent the bug to occur when you receive the quest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Hanar's fate is sealed until such time as EA releases a patch repairing this bug.

Using the saved game editor is an option, but as always it presents the risk of having your copy bumped out of multiplayer or may mess up the ph balance in your pool.

I experienced this bug and will be sure to avoid it in my 2nd play through, but for now there's nothing that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Without using *Mass Effect 3 Gibbed save editor*, it's not possible to drop a quest. 
So if you don't wanna risk to corrupt your save might be to get a previous save, just before to get the quest.

Otherwise you can still try to edit the save, but make sure you made a back up of the original save.

[Here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995452-/62195628) you can find a procedure to avoid the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I found was to load a save game prior to starting quest--preferably even prior to landing on Citadel. Sorry that other answers do not seem to understand that Bioware rushed out a potentially great game, yet killed aspirations with a plethora of bugs. This game is as buggy as Skyrim! Do NOT do anything to interrupt this quest until completed, or you will be forced to restart-or simply leave quest unfinished.