# Fixing the Citadel: Hanar Diplomat sidequest

Tags: mass-effect-3

While playing *Mass Effect 3*, I couldn't access the quest terminals. What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you drop and reacquire the Hanar Diplomat quest?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57052/can-you-drop-and-reacquire-the-hanar-diplomat-quest)

Answer (score 4):

You can fix it if you have the PC version of Mass Effect 3. Follow this tutorial. It worked for me. :D

Answer (score 3):

Yea the terminal can get buggy sometimes. What you do, if I recall properly is:

1. Pick up the hanar quest
2. Proceed to the terminals marked on the embassies level
3. After locating and activating, short conversation exchange will occur. After this happens the terminal will sometimes still be marked as a "go-to"
4. Proceed anyways to the Dock Holdings, and a new terminal will be marked as a "go-to" on that level.
5. After activating that terminal, head to the far right of the Dock Holdings level to get to your next "go-to" terminal
6. After activating that terminal, head back to the terminal you accessed first on this level and activate that one again.
7. Then proceed to the embassies and head to the office suit on the left to talk to Bau, the spectre who gave you the mission.

If you get confused, feel free to refer to
http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Hanar_Diplomat

Answer (score 3):

it's a known bug.  After you start the quest if you leave the citadel you can't activate the terminals.

Answer (score 0):

I had this and ended up restarting the Citadel Mission (via load screen).

When I restarted, I picked up the Hanar quest and also made a point of not activating the detection stuff through the Spectre console.

Other than that, I pretty much followed http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Hanar_Diplomat